# How to get payment method selected magento 2

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway

I need to get the 'Cash On Delivery' payment method if it is selected.
I Cannot get the payment method name. The
`getMethodInstance()` and `getTitle()` are not working. See the code I used below:

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote();

$it = $itemsCollection->getPayment();
$iit = $it->getMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to get `MethodInstance` from quote:

```
$quote = $cart->getQuote();

$method = $quote->getMethodInstance();

if ($method) {
   $method->getCode();
}
```

One more, directly trying to use Object Manager is not the best practice.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCode() on null

Comment: How to resolve this

Comment: Checking it. For example: `if (null !== $payment->getCode())`

Comment: I can't understand pls elaborate, I'm using this function in onepage.php file

Comment: Check my code again.

Comment: Thanks @khoa TruongDinh it's working.. but no I need to get cash on delivery alone final step I hope you'll help me I'm beginner

Comment: Final step? Which is the step?